# Sigma notation only for odd iterations

Tags: notation, summation

$ \sum_{i=0}^{5}{i^2} = 0^2+1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2+5^2 = 55 $

How to write this Sigma notation only for odd numbers: $ 1^2+3^2+5^2 = 35 $ ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could write
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{3} f(2i-1).
$$
Otherwise it is allowed to write
$$
\sum_{1 \leq i\leq 5, i \text{ odd}} f(i).
$$
(Here in your example $f(i) = i^2$ of course).

So in general whatever condition you have on the index, you can write that underneath the sum. In general you will find some people prefer one thing over another.

Comment: Sorry, I mean notation for general situation. If there will be not $ i^2 $ but $ f(i) $

Comment: Second variant suits me if this notation is acceptable, thank you! :)

Comment: Yes, sure, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Usually when conditions are added the upper index is not used, so the subscript would be $1\le i\le 5,\ i\text{ odd}$.

Comment: @Charles: I agree. Your way is better.

Comment: @Thomas you have typo in your current answer: $ 1 \leq 1\leq 5 $ should probably be $ 1 \leq i\leq 5 $ :)

Answer (score 3):

Just use the following for any $f(i)$:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n f(2i+1)$$

Edit: Sorry, I somehow mistook the question for "even".

Comment: With the little caveat that $2i$ is not odd.