# notation for Sumation of Sumation for only for odd iterations

Tags: summation, notation

I need to write a summation in summation whether the inner summation should iterate from one through all odd numbers to the teration of the outer summation which goes from 1 to $\infty$... Something like...

$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \sum_{1 \le k \le i, k\text{ odd}}^{i} \text{expression}
$$

This notation I found in:
[Sigma notation only for odd iterations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188424/sigma-notation-only-for-odd-iterations)

However, I am still wondering, if there is any other, more elegant way how to do it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd argue that using $2k-1$ **is** the elegant way to do it:
$$\large\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^{\lceil i/2\rceil}(\text{expression using $2k-1$})$$
What you wrote in your post is one alternative, though it can be written a bit more cleanly as:
$$\large\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{\substack{k=1\\k\text{ odd}}}^i(\text{expression using $k$})$$

Comment: The first expression was what I was looking for, however, you re right. When I see both option next to each other, I prefer the odd notation... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{i+1}{2}\rfloor}$$ then change the $k$ inside your summation to $2k-1$. Not sure if that is the kind of thing you are looking for.